# Issue of Sending Bulk Data as XML tag to SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml

I am inserting bulk data(serial number,pin number) to DB.Before inserting,the data from datatable is binded into XML tag.Here the pin number is encrypted one...as follows,

```
strXml = "<?xml<pre lang="c#"></pre> version=" + @"""1.0"" encoding=" + @"""iso-8859-1""?><batch>";
strPinXml =strPinXml + "<data cardid="+@"""" +strid+@""""+" pinnumber=" + @"""" + myRC4Engine.CryptedText + @"""" + "></data>";
strXml = strXml + strPinXml + "</batch>";
```

Problem is after inserting into db, to verify whether the actual pinnumber(encrypted format in db) is inserted, i decrypted the pinnumber and found that,

> The first digit in all data are displaced by (’)single quote and last
>   digit for some pinnumber is empty (if the pinnumber is-œA_¡/Ì·ÞvËÛ
>   (ie)ending in Û for that pins last digit is empty).

---

### Please note that i'am using SQL server 2000 in this application

### Please provide the solution to resolve this issue

## Result as follows

Pins before inserting into db

> - Pinnumber(While inserting)
>
>   - (Encrypted format) --- (Decrypted format)
>   - šA [¦,ÈµØzËÚ  ---------  7613051524692
>   - œA *¡/Ì•ÞvËÛ  ---------  1687765748683*
>   - ™@ X¦!Ï´ÝÎÛ ---------  4770086471383
>   - žA Z¡+É¹ÝwÏÒ  ---------   3642720979218
>   - •O Q¢(Ë¹Þ{ËÛ  ---------   8879412945686
>   - ŸO^¡,È¶Ý}Î×  ---------   2846751673342

Pins retrieved from db after insertion

> - Pinnumber (Retrieved from db)  ----  Retrieved pinnumber
>
>   - (Encrypted format)  --------------- (Decrypted format)
>   - A [¦,ÈµØzËÚ  -------------------  ’613051524692
>   - A _¡/Ì•ÞvËÛ      -------------------  ’68776574868
>   - @ X¦!Ï´ÝÎÛ  ------------------  ’77008647138
>   - A Z¡+É¹ÝwÏÒ   -----------------  ’642720979218
>   - O Q¢(Ë¹Þ{ËÛ  -------------------  ’879412945686
>   - O ^¡,È¶Ý}Î×      ------------------  ’846751673342

### Application coding as follows

```
try
{
    RC4Engine myRC4Engine = new RC4Engine();
    myRC4Engine.EncryptionKey = "ab48495fdjk4950dj39405fk";

    strXml = "<?xml version=" + @"""1.0"" encoding=" + @"""iso-8859-1""?> <batch>";

    foreach (DataRow lobjbaseBatchDetail in dt.Rows)
    {
        myRC4Engine.InClearText = lobjbaseBatchDetail[3].ToString();
        myRC4Engine.Encrypt();

        strCardid = lobjbaseBatchDetail[0].ToString();
        strBatchid = lobjbaseBatchDetail[1].ToString();
        strid = strCardid + strBatchid + lobjbaseBatchDetail[2].ToString();
        strPinXml =strPinXml + "<data cardid="+@"""" +strid+@""""+
                " pinnumber=" + @"""" + myRC4Engine.CryptedText + @"""" + "></data>";
    }
        strXml = strXml + strPinXml + "</batch>";
        SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[1];

        arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@BATCHUPLOAD_XML", SqlDbType.Text );
        arrParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        arrParam[0].Value = strXml;

        iResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objTrans, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "test_proc", arrParam);
        objTrans.Commit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    objTrans.Rollback();
    throw new Exception("Upload failed :" + ex.Message);
}
```

## procedure

```
create procedure test_proc
(
    @BATCHUPLOAD_XML text
)
as
begin
    DECLARE @idoc INT
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @BATCHUPLOAD_XML
    insert into test_table_new
    SELECT cardid,pinnumber
    FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/batch/data')
    WITH (cardid varchar(100) '@cardid', pinnumber nvarchar(200) '@pinnumber')
    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't write the xml by hand.  Let C#'s LinqToXml do it for you and it won't make mistakes.

You could write it like:

```
try
{
    RC4Engine myRC4Engine = new RC4Engine();
    myRC4Engine.EncryptionKey = "ab48495fdjk4950dj39405fk";

    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "iso-8859-1", null),
        new XElement("batch"));

    foreach (DataRow lobjbaseBatchDetail in dt.Rows)
    {
        myRC4Engine.InClearText = lobjbaseBatchDetail[3].ToString();
        myRC4Engine.Encrypt();

        strCardid = lobjbaseBatchDetail[0].ToString();
        strBatchid = lobjbaseBatchDetail[1].ToString();
        strid = strCardid + strBatchid + lobjbaseBatchDetail[2].ToString();
        XElement data = new XElement("data");
        data.Add(new XAttribute("cardid", strid));
        data.Add(new XAttribute("pinnumber", myRC4Engine.CryptedText));
        doc.Root.Add(data);
    }
        SqlParameter[] arrParam = new SqlParameter[1];

        arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@BATCHUPLOAD_XML", SqlDbType.Text );
        arrParam[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        arrParam[0].Value = doc.Declaration.ToString() +
                            doc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);

        iResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objTrans, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "test_proc", arrParam);
        objTrans.Commit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    objTrans.Rollback();
    throw new Exception("Upload failed :" + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: --Thanks for your comment.Now,i'am engaged in another work.I will update the result,after implementing your coding approach.

Answer (score 0):

RC4-encrypted information is binary data, not text. CryptedText shouldn't be typed as string. To wrap binary data in XML, you probably want to use the binary data's BASE64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment..As you said RC4 encrypted information(binary data) is converted into a string finally.So, crypted Text is typed as string.There is no problem in that.

Comment: "Converting" binary to string may not preserve binary data. The examples you gave fail to unambiguously describe binary data. Two examples: 1. If the binary data you hope to store in XML includes characters whose ASCII values are below 32, it can't be represented by "converting" to string and wrapping into XML. Sub-32 ASCII characters are *explicitly* invalid in XML. 2. Many binary values will "convert" differently depending on the locale/culture settings in place. This is why I recommend BASE64, which encodes (as opposed to converts) binary data into a string in a reversible, unambiguous way.